# Why isn't vagrant private network not set up when configured within provider block?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to understand why putting the network options in the provider block of Vagrantfile doesn't work.  For example, this seems to work:

```
config.vm.define "mymachine" do |vbox_config|
  vbox_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.10"

  vbox_config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end
end
```

but this doesn't work (network is not accessible):

```
config.vm.define "mymachine" do |vbox_config|

  vbox_config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.ssh.forward_agent = true
    vb.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.10"
  end
end
```

It seems like I would want to set the network options to be specific to a provider and structure the Vagrantfile like the latter.  Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set non-provider specific configuration inside a provider block you have to use a different syntax:

```
config.vm.define "mymachine" do |vbox_config|

  vbox_config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb, override|
    override.ssh.forward_agent = true
    override.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.10"
  end
end
```

Indeed, the first argument is for provider specific configuration (e.g. `vb.customize`), while the second is for overrides. Please see [the documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/configuration.html) for more information.